# How to arrange 4 figures in one page at top and bottom of the page

Tags: floats, positioning

I'm gonna place 4 figures in a page, where 2 figures will be at the top of each column and the rest will be located at the bottom of two columns, just like image below:

[image]

But I have no clear idea to set the positioning options for those figures.

Here is a MWE (I'd just used `t` and `b`, which is not leading to target formation):

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{image}
    \caption{up-left}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{image}
    \caption{bottom-left}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure}[b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{image}
    \caption{up-right}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure}[b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{image}
    \caption{bottom-left}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Could you give me some advice in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}
    \caption{up-left}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}
    \caption{bottom-left}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}
    \caption{up-right}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}
    \caption{bottom-left}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-5]

\lipsum[1-5]

\lipsum[1-5]


\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution does not work for my real document!
Seemingly, the volume of the text between the figures does matter, a lot. How can I discern the best text volume between figures to acquire the right formation with the proposed solution?...

Comment: @Roboticist stick them all as early as possible especially in 2-col mode, you need to see any figures that end in the first column before any potential column break

Comment: also set `topnumber` and `botnumber` to 1 so you don't get them stacked

Comment: This was one of the amazingly crazy problem's, with which I've faced up to now to work with LaTeX. Your suggestions are, undoubtedly, valuable and functional, but in this case, I'd just fix the issue with successive juxtapositions of the figures and text between them. I believe that some functionalities in LaTeX don't sound to behave completely deterministic and really annoying!
All in all, I accept your answer, because that's useful.

Comment: @Roboticist latex's float position is completely deterministic:-) see Frank's opus for the gory details http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020